# Default for delegate dictionary pattern

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates

Consider this code:

```
switch (number)
{
    case 1:
        Number = (int)SmsStatusEnum.Sent;
        break;
    case 2:
        Number = (int)SmsStatusEnum.Delivered;
        break;
    case 3:
        Number = (int)SmsStatusEnum.Failed;
        break;
    default:
        Number = (int)SmsStatusEnum.Failed;
        break;
}
return Number;
```

I have a `switch case` that has default.So if the `number` is not 1,2 or 3 result to be `Failed`.
So i convert the code to delegate dictionary:

```
var statuses = new Dictionary<int, Func<SmsStatusEnum>>
{
    {1,()=> SmsStatusEnum.Sent},
    {2,()=> SmsStatusEnum.Delivered},
    {3,()=> SmsStatusEnum.Failed},
};
```

How can I set default for delegate dictionary pattern?

Comment: [Un]Fortunately, the standard Dictionary class provides no mechanism to set a "default" value (or delegate) for a missed key-fetch. (It's not necessarily a "bad thing" - it just isn't a ".NET core thing".)

Comment: I would say that using dictionary for this is not that pretty solution, `Enum.TryParse` much better. Your enum struct has everything you need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To set a default you would just wrap the `Dictionary` in a function

```
SmsStatusEnum GetStatus(int value) { 
  Func<SmsStatusEnum> func;
  if (!statuses.TryGetValue(value, out func)) { 
    // Default value
    return SmsStatusEnum.Failed;
  }
  return func();
}
```

In this case though I don't quite see why you are storing a `Func<SmsStatusEnum>` here.  Does the actual code involve computation in the `Func<SmsStatusEnum>` implementation?  If so then this is indeed a good pattern.  If not then you may want to consider just storing a `Dictionary<int, SmsStatusEnum>` directly

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but your solution looks bad for me. You don't need any extra dictionary to work with enums, you can create a new method and use [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
SmsStatusEnum GetStatus(int value)
{     
    SmsStatusEnum val; 
    if(Enum.TryParse<SmsStatusEnum>(value.ToString(), out val))
        return val;
    else
        return SmsStatusEnum.Failed;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, along with redefining the enum numbers like this:
Use @Tony 's answer above and set your enums like such:
Truthfully you only really even need the TryParse if you're expecting funky (crap) from the input intStatusNumber (@Tony 's int value)

<code>
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
    public enum SmsStatusEnum
    {
        Sent = 1,
        Delivered = 2,
        Failed = 3,
    };

Answer (score 0):

I go with this way:

```
var validStatues = new int[] {1, 3, 2};
if (!validStatues.Any(x=>x == statusId))
{
    statusId = 0;
}

var statuses = new Dictionary<int, Func<SmsStatusEnum>>
{
    {1,()=> SmsStatusEnum.Sent},
    {2,()=> SmsStatusEnum.Delivered},
    {3,()=> SmsStatusEnum.Failed},
    {0,()=> SmsStatusEnum.Failed},
};
```

Comment: This invalidates the need for a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` because now every lookup is linear.